# AWS-SDK fails on first request after Express server reloads

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the AWS-SDK to upload images to S3 from my Express server. After the server reloads, the first request always gives a `Signature does not match` error, but then works as expected for subsequent requests.

Does anyone have any ideas of what could be going wrong? If it helps, I am using an IAM role to authenticate with AWS, configured by the environment variables `AWS_ROLE_ARN` and `AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE`. Thanks in advance!